# MLP learning rate optimization with GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, mlp

I'm trying to tune the hyperparameters of MLP classifier using GridSearchCV but facing the following issue:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan.


Details: 

ValueError: learning rate 0.01 is not supported. 

  FitFailedWarning)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan.

Details: 

ValueError: learning rate 0.02 is not supported

........
```

Code:

```
clf = MLPClassifier()
params= {
   'hidden_layer_sizes': hidden_layers_generator(X,np.arange(1,17,1)),
   'solver': ['sgd'],
   'momentum': np.arange(0.1,1.1,0.1),
   'learning_rate': np.arange(0.01,1.01,0.01),
   'max_iter': np.arange(100,2100,100)}
grid = GridSearchCV(clf, params, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
grid.fit(X, y)
grid_mean_scores = grid.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
pd.DataFrame(grid.cv_results_)[['mean_test_score', 'std_test_score', 'params']]
```

The code of hidden_layers_generator is as follows:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
def hidden_layers_generator(df,hidden_layers):
  hd_sizes = []
  for l in range(1, len(hidden_layers)):
    comb = combinations_with_replacement(np.arange(1,len(df.columns),10), l)
    hd_sizes.append(list(comb))
  return hd_sizes
```

Here's a small snippet of X and y dataframes:

```
X.head()
    sl      sw      pl      pw
0   5.1     3.5     1.4     0.2
1   4.9     3.0     1.4     0.2
2   4.7     3.2     1.3     0.2
3   4.6     3.1     1.5     0.2
4   5.0     3.6     1.4     0.2
```

```
y.head()
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  you look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) of `MLPClassifier`, you will see that `learning_rate` parameter is not what you think but instead, it is a kind of scheduler. What you want is `learning_rate_init` parameter. So change this line in the configuration:

```
   'learning_rate': np.arange(0.01,1.01,0.01),
```

to

```
   'learning_rate_init': np.arange(0.01,1.01,0.01),
```

Comment: Thank you @Mustafa Aydın I tried your answer with an 'adaptive' learning rate but now I'm getting the following error:   

`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:536: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan.
Details:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'`

Comment: @houdabenhar Can you update your question with the code you tried which gave this error? If the code snippet is short, you can also comment here.

Comment: It's the same as the previous one with the learning_rate HP modified and learning_rate_init added as follows:
    `params= {
    'hidden_layer_sizes': hidden_layers_generator(X,np.arange(1,17,1)),
    'solver': ['sgd'],
    'momentum': np.arange(0.1,1.1,0.1),
    'learning_rate': ['adaptive'],
    'max_iter': np.arange(100,2100,100),
    'learning_rate_init': np.arange(0.01,1.01,0.01)}`

Comment: @houdabenhar Can you tell what `hidden_layers_generator` is doing exactly?

Comment: @houdabenhar please use some [dummy data](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html) to post a [mcve]. Avoid posting code in the comments. And what indeed is `hidden_layers_generator`?

Comment: @MustafaAydın it's a function I wrote to generate lists of different numbers of layers with different number of neurons. 
the first param is a dataframe which the function uses to generate a list of different neurons numbers starting from 1 to the number of neurons in the input layer (the number of columns in my training set i.e. X). The second param is a list of hidden layers numbers (I want to test the model with one hidden layer then 2 then 3..to 16). I hope this makes some sense to you. it outputs something like this [[(1,), (21,),(41,),(61,)], [(1, 1),(1, 21),(1, 41)..],[..],.]

Comment: @MustafaAydın I hope this makes some sense to you. I can provide the code if you want

Comment: @desertnaut where else can I provide the code? thanks

Comment: @houdabenhar I see, you need to flatten those list of lists of tuples to list of tuples because that's what `GridSearch` expects: a list of parameter configurations. So pass `[tup for a_list in hidden_layers_generator(X,np.arange(1,17,1)) for tup in a_list]` as the value of `'hidden_layer_sizes'` in the `params` dict.

Comment: @houdabenhar if the code for `hidden_layers_generator` is *relevant* to the issue, you shoukd have included it in your post; if it is *not* relevant, you shoukd have omitted `hidden_layers_generator` altogether from the question. SO does not work by throwing our code here as is, please **re-read** how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @MustafaAydın you're right! It's working now thanks appreciate it!

Comment: @desertnaut it didn't seem to be relevant at first since the main issue was indicating a problem in the learning_rate HP and the second issue only appeared after the main one was solved! Anyway I have included the hidden_layers_generator code. Thanks

Comment: @houdabenhar Glad it worked! you may consider accepting / upvoting the answer if you wish, to signal others that the issue is resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers